# Navigating through Dates on a UserForm Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have created the below userform to navigate between dates: 13/06/2014 to 10/07/2014.

[UserForm http://im50.gulfup.com/hyS1Fo.png](http://im50.gulfup.com/hyS1Fo.png)

The idea is that if the current date is before 13/06/2014 then the Date2 variable is set as "13/06/2014" and if the current date is after 10/07/2014 then the Date2 variable is set at "10/07/2014"

The problem I am having is that the code for the "Next" button is not working as it is supposed to. It just navigates to the next day and then stops at that, where it should keep navigating all the way till "10/07/2014"

Below is my code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim DateLooper As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim Date1 As Date
Dim Date2 As Date

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Date1 = Date
Date2 = Date

If Date1 < DateValue("June 13, 2014") Then
Date2 = DateValue("June 13, 2014")
End If

If Date1 > DateValue("July 10, 2014") Then
Date2 = DateValue("July 10, 2014")
End If

EndDate = DateValue("July 10, 2014")

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        For DateLooper = Date2 To EndDate
                UserForm1.Label3.Caption = Format(DateLooper, "dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy")

                'code goes here

                Date2 = DateLooper
                Exit For
        Next DateLooper
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Date1 = Date
Date2 = Date

If Date1 < DateValue("June 13, 2014") Then
Date2 = DateValue("June 13, 2014")
End If

If Date1 > DateValue("July 10, 2014") Then
Date2 = DateValue("July 10, 2014")
End If

EndDate = DateValue("July 10, 2014")

    With ws
        For DateLooper = (Date2 + 1) To EndDate

                UserForm1.Label3.Caption = Format(DateLooper, "dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy")

                'code goes here

                Date2 = DateLooper
                Exit Sub
        Next DateLooper

        If (DateLooper - 1) = EndDate Then
            MsgBox "End Date reached"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Also I would appreciate if someone could help in the code for the "Previous" button, I have tried `For DateLooper = (Date2 - 1) To 2 Step -1` but it also did not work correctly :(

Here is a link to my workbook: https://db.tt/aM7PZIDs

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I noticed a few things in your code. First, there's no need for a loop. Your Next/Previous buttons are what you want to increment the date, not a loop. I also noticed that you had a lot of unnecessary variables.

Try the following code. Note, I tested this on a UserForm I threw together, so you may need to adjust your form before it will work.

```
Option Explicit

Dim dtStr As Date

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim Date1 As Date
Date1 = Date

If Date1 < dateValue("June 13, 2014") Then
    Date1 = dateValue("June 13, 2014")
ElseIf Date1 > dateValue("July 10, 2014") Then
    Date1 = dateValue("July 10, 2014")
End If

UserForm1.Label3.Caption = Format(Date1, "dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy")

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

With UserForm1.Label3
    dtStr = Mid(.Caption, InStr(1, .Caption, ",") + 2)
    If dtStr = dateValue("June 13, 2014") Then Call Err_Msg: Exit Sub
    .Caption = Format(dtStr - 1, "dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy")
End With

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

With UserForm1.Label3
    dtStr = Mid(.Caption, InStr(1, .Caption, ",") + 2)
    If dtStr = dateValue("July 10, 2014") Then Call Err_Msg: Exit Sub
    .Caption = Format(dtStr + 1, "dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy")
End With

End Sub

Sub Err_Msg()

MsgBox "Beginning or End Date Reached!", vbCritical

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect!!! It is working exactly as I intended! A question though, what does the line `dtStr = Mid(.Caption, InStr(1, .Caption, ",") + 2)` do exactly? I have been trying to understand it but can't seem to figure out the `InStr` function.

Comment: UPDATE: Never mind, I got it now. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you do not have any condition statements before your Exit statements within your loop, so each for loop is only going to perform once, every time

put a conditional If-Then statement before the Exit statement, or get rid of the Exit statements if you don't need them

Comment: Thanks for the hint; but after removing the `Exit For` & `Exit Sub` statements, it now jumps to the last date (10/07/2014) every time I press "Next" and then nothing happens. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: @CaptainABC sorry i missunderstood your original question.  i see you have your answer now, happy coding